# jquery : recreating a jquery menu, where am I going wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, css

trying to recreate this jquery menu to leanr how it was made but I can't seem to get it working right, I've copied the code initially but something is wrong, any ideas? Thanks a lot

Original: http://www.aldomatic.com/jqm/fb-menu-style/

Copied to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6H4Fx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include jQuery Mobile's JS and CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.aldomatic.com/jqm/fb-menu-style/css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.aldomatic.com/jqm/fb-menu-style/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
```

[Working here in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/6H4Fx/1/)

Comment: thanks for the help, any chance you know why the 'color can't be set using the .active class? When I change it to color: #911; nothing happens?? http://jsfiddle.net/6H4Fx/2/

Comment: Because it is being overridden by `#menu ul li a:link, #menu ul li a:visited`, try changing color for it also.